# Breaking the Build, Why is it a bad thing?

Tags: continuous-integration

When I started building a continuous integration server, I ran across the statement "It's bad to break the build [of the code]."  After finishing that project I came to the conclusion that

1. "Breaking the build." was a catchy phrase that was being thrown around a lot because of the alliteration, or
2. I wasn't understanding a key element of Continuous Integration.

So my question is in the spirit of #2: **why is breaking the build a bad thing?**

Comment: typically breaking anything is bad, other than 'breaking into the buisness', etc..

Comment: If you "break the build," you no longer have a functioning system, which is kind of the point of continuous integration.  How can that *not* be bad?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because if other people check out your broken changes, they won't be able to work, or if they do they will do so less efficiently.

It also means you're not properly testing your changes before you commit, which is key in CI.

Comment: So by breaking you mean there is code that doesn't compile being committed to the source repository?

Comment: Right. "Breaking the build" refers, usually, to committing code you haven't tested which then wont compile (or otherwise spectacularly fails) and prevents your co-workers from... you know, working :)

Comment: That's the most straightforward application. In the most extreme application, it would be any change that introduces a bug. I would say the two most common usages are 1 - causes it to not compile, or 2 - causes a significant bug that inhibits other people's work. Obviously you'll can't always commit bug-free (oh boy if you could!) but you do need to make sure that your changes don't somehow keep menus from appearing, cause lots of error messages to appear, and certainly not cause compile errors. (Most compile errors in checkins are when you forget one of the files to check in, btw.)

Comment: I should point out there isn't a fast and hard definition of what breaking the build is, but "you know it when you see it".

Comment: You'll often be able to define how 'broken' the build is by the frustration levels of those who have just checked out your code.

Answer (score 24):

Be very careful in labeling "Breaking the Build" as a bad thing.  It is something that needs immediate attention, but it is also a very normal and expected part of the development cycle.  This is why Continuous Integration is so useful -- it tells you immediately when the build is broken, and what change set caused it.  It helps you get back on track quickly.

If your culture penalizes "Breaking the Build", then you are in danger of cultivating a toxic work environment.  Again, consider it to be something that needs immediate attention, but don't label it as "bad".

Comment: Glad you said that.  My comment certainly implied that it was a "bad thing in general", as opposed to a "bad thing you should attempt to solve when it happens."

Comment: Bad you should try and get work done when someone keeps breaking the build.. that's bad.

Comment: @Choco My point was to avoid a culture of punishment around breaking the build. That sort of culture will ultimately dissuade people from committing more.  You can't break the build if you don't commit!  Better to put policies in place to avoid the possibility of breaking the build.  I haven't had to deal with a "broken build" in years, due to automation policies that require compilers/linters/unit tests to pass before code gets committed to shared branches.

Answer (score 13):

From Martin Fowler http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html

> The whole point of working with CI is
>   that you're always developing on a
>   known stable base. It's not a bad
>   thing for the mainline build to break,
>   although if it's happening all the
>   time it suggests people aren't being
>   careful enough about updating and
>   building locally before a commit. When
>   the mainline build does break,
>   however, it's important that it gets
>   fixed fast.

Answer (score 8):

Because if other people checkout the changes, they won´t be able to work...
[image]
This image is copyrighted to Geek & Poke under a [Creative Commons License](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/2.0/de/deed.en_GB)

Answer (score 4):

It you break the build as has happend to me yesterday. When your team-mates try and use the sourcecode. It will not build. Therfore they will struggle to test the work that they are doing. It get worse the bigger your team.

Answer (score 3):

Surely the whole point of continuous integration is to identify problems early. Daily or more frequent check ins are required to reduce conflicts to a manageable size.

You should get an up to date copy of the repository and build locally. This will tell you if your proposed check in will break the build. You resolve any issues and then check in.

In this way the integration issues are kept local and easy to fix.

Answer (score 2):

Breaking the build has dire implications for the project schedule (and the blood pressure of team-mates)
=> Other developers who then get latest version can no longer build there own changes, delaying them
=> Continuous integration will break, meaning that formal testing can be delayed

Many version control tools (e.g. TFS) can prevent developers from checking in code which does not compile or pass unit or code analysis tests.

Answer (score 1):

Once builds start breaking, people get reluctant to get the latest changes, and you begin the deadly spiral towards Big Bang integration of changes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think breaking the build is necessarily a bad thing, as long as there is a well-known, working branch or tag in the repository. That said, make your own branch in the repository if you know your code is going the break the build today, but you will fix it next week. Then later you can merge back into trunk.

Comment: You're mostly right, except that if you're making your own branch, that isn't continuous integration, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Because it means someone has done something bad (or at least, some changes have clashed) and you can no longer build and deploy your system.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking the build means that you committed code to a shared repository that either (a) does not compile, or (b) does not work (fails unit tests).  Anyone else who's developing from that shared repository is going to have to deal with the broken code you committed until it is fixed.  That will cause a loss of productivity for the entire team.